# ASP.NET MVC 4 Routes - controller/id vs controller/action/id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to add a route to the default one, so that I have both urls working:

1. `http://www.mywebsite.com/users/create`
2. `http://www.mywebsite.com/users/1`

This will make the first route work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, the second route won't work obviously.

This will make the second route work, but will break the first one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Book",
     url: "books/{id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "users", action = "Details" }
);
```

How to combine the two route configurations so that both URLs work?
I apologize if there is already a question like this on SO, I wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: Should your second URL contain "books" instead of "users"?  You mention that the second route makes the second url work, but breaks the first, but the second URL does not apply to the second route unless it matches the pattern "books/{id}".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The key is to put more specific routes first.  So put the "Book" route first.  **Edit** I guess you also need a constraint to only allow numbers to match the "id" part of this route. **End edit**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Book",
    url: "books/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "users", action = "Details" },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And ensure that the "id" parameter in your "Details" action is an int:

```
// "users" controller
public ActionResult books(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```

This way, the "Books" route will not catch a URL like `/users/create` (since the second parameter is reqiured to be a number), and so will fall through to the next ("Default") route.

Comment: Yeah, no - it doesn't fall through like this. When you type /users/create, server expects an {id} instead of "create", and gives a  "Broken link" error page.

Comment: @ArmanBimatov my mistake. I am rusty. You also need a constraint in the route then, I guess.  I've updated my answer above.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: Nice, it works. Never knew about constraints in defining routing.