# I need to take the controller action's name out of the URL, but don't know how

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Example: I would like to view a Contract with an ID of 12483, so I would like to use this URL:

```
/Contract/12483
```

I can't do this in ASP.NET MVC because the ASP.NET route exepects /{controller}/{action}/{id} to be able to route to the needed code to handle the request so I would have to do this:

```
/Contract/View/12483
```

This is not RESTful, however.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038284/asp-net-mvc-4-routes-controller-id-vs-controller-action-id

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can use the name of `ActionResult` as `Index` instead of `view`.

Or you can use this in your `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Book",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Contract", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```