# MVC 4.0 Routing "Area" Prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I Guess my question is very stuppied, but i could not find any awenser or link that worked fine, so.

The point is, I want my url to reflect my folder strcuture. Witch is:

```
~/Controllers/Admin/ 
~/Controllers/Supply/
```

My routeconfig look like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Admin",
                 url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}",
                 namespaces: new [] {"Web_Intranet.Controllers.Admin"}
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Supply",
                 url: "Supply/{controller}/{action}",
                 namespaces: new [] {"Web_Intranet.Controllers.Supply"}
            );
```

The problem is that if you type on the brower url the following:

```
localhost:4342/admin/users/showall
OR
localhost:4342/supply/users/showall
```

**Both will work!** I assume that the routing checks wheter you pass a valid "controller" and "action" and chooses the first one that matches the condition.

How can I create a valid routing config that will not work if the corresponding prefix doesn´t match?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the configuration you should add for each *Area*;

`~/Areas/Admin/AdminAreaRegistration.cs`

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApp.Areas.Admin
{
  public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
  {
    public override string AreaName
    {
      get
      {
        return "Admin";
      }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
      context.MapRoute(
          "Admin_default",
          "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure that Route_Name is unique

Comment: I know i metioned the term "Area", but I not using the Areas on the projet. Will this still work?

Comment: May be this will help you - [ASP.NET MVC 4 Routes - controller/id vs controller/action/id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038284/asp-net-mvc-4-routes-controller-id-vs-controller-action-id)