# Can I do {controller}\{id} with a Guid instead of {controller}\{action}\{id}

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking to set up simple routes so that {controller}/{id} would default to {controller}/details/{id}. I've set it up like in this post: [ASP.NET MVC 4 Routes - controller/id vs controller/action/id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038284/asp-net-mvc-4-routes-controller-id-vs-controller-action-id)

But that post suggests for the routes to work I would need `int` {id} values. We use Guid ids.

Here is what I have:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); 

        routes.MapRoute
        (
            name: "Detail",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute
        (
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Submission", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Can I do this with `Guid` ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your current route definition is, It will work for your particular request, but will break the existing default routing.When you try to access `Home/About`, it will send you to the Details action of Home!.

To solve this,what you can do is to pass a route constraint where you can pass the regex for `Guid`.

This should work fine.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute
        (
            name: "Detail",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional   },
            constraints: new { id = "[A-Z0-9]{8}-([A-Z0-9]{4}-){3}[A-Z0-9]{12}" }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And change your action method parameter type to `Guid`.

```
public class ProjectController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Details(Guid id)
    {          
        return View();
    }
}
```

For the request `yourSite/project/someValidGuid`, now it will send the request to the `Details` action on `ProjectController`

Comment: That gives me 'The resource cannot be found.' with this path: http://localhost:63595/project/a2176b66-6168-e511-b962-00215e466552

Comment: Are you sure you have a Details action method which has param called Id of type `Guid` . see my edit in the answer. It totally worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that the way your routes are set up will do is hide any other action methods. To be sure that doesn't happen, you can qualify the type of your `id` in your route:

```
routes.MapRoute
(
    name: "Detail",
    url: "{controller}/{id:Guid}",
    defaults: new { action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Otherwise, it will look at any data type for that `{id}` parameter. So a string (like a different action), would be send to the Details action method.

Comment: This defaults to Index. But it doesn't error, so that's a step in the right direction.

Comment: Add the "controller" to the defaults at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It should work without issue.  Verified by testing locally.

localhost/Submission/Index/c98b3df8-de39-4735-a82c-07de43e72233

```
public class SubmissionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(Guid id)
    {

    }
}
```